# Javascript - pull values of an element with matching property in one array and save to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays, sendInstalls and sendUsers.  Both arrays have a property called objId with matching values across the 2 arrays.  The arrays are not sorted in any particular order.

What I want to do:

1. For each element of sendUsers array, find the element in the sendInstalls array with a matching objId property
2. Return the devToken property value of that element in sendInstalls
3. Save the value of that property in the objToken property of the sendUsers array (which already exists)

I tried the below:

```
            sendUsers.forEach(function(theSentUser){

                function findWithAttr(array, attr, value){
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1){
                    if(array[i][attr] === value){
                        return i;
                        };
                    };
                };

                var matchInstall = findWithAttr(sendInstalls,'devToken',theSentUser.objId);
                console.log(matchInstall);
                theSentUser.objToken = sendInstalls[matchInstall].devToken;
            });
```

However the console.log(matchInstall) line returns rows of 'undefined' instead of matching array indexes.

Haven't pasted the data because it is user sensitive, but is there anything immediately apparent that is wrong with the above?  if data is essential to resolving this I can try and anonymise an excerpt and update this question.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off thanks to Vivek for quick response.

Per my comments on Vivek's answer, the main problem was 'devToken' was the wrong key to compare to theSentUser.objId so it was always coming out as undefined.  Dumb mistake, apologies and impossible for Vivek to have picked up not knowing the structure of the arrays.

I also needed to introduce some error handling for matchInstall.

Here is the code that worked in case anyone else is trying to achieve a similar thing.

```
    function findWithAttr(array, attr, value){
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1){
                    if(array[i][attr] === value){
                        return i;
                        };
                    };
                };

    sendUsers.forEach(function(theSentUser){

                var matchInstall = findWithAttr(sendInstalls,'usrId',theSentUser.objId);

                if(typeof (matchInstall) === "undefined"){
                    theSentUser.objToken = 0
                    console.log('error')
                } else {
                    theSentUser.objToken = sendInstalls[matchInstall]['devToken']
                    console.log(theSentUser.objToken)
                }; 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you don't mention the structure of both your arrays in your question but assuming you have it defined and coded correctly, you probably just need to define the function `findwithAttr` outside the loop where you traverse the `SendUsers` array like so (untested code):

```
 function findWithAttr(array, attr, value){
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1){
                if(array[i][attr] === value){
                    return i;
                    };
                };
            };

 sendUsers.forEach(function(theSentUser){

            var matchInstall = findWithAttr(sendInstalls,'devToken',theSentUser.objId);
            console.log(matchInstall);
            theSentUser.objToken = sendInstalls[matchInstall].devToken;
        });
```

You were defining and using the function within the loop which was probably causing the trouble. I hope this gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks - a bit hard without posting the actual arrays, I appreciate.  I actually solved this one, the main problem was that 'devToken' was the wrong key to compare in findWithAttr.  Dumb mistake, apologies. I'll post answer with what worked shortly.